# Sphinx: Place heading between automethod entries

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm using Sphinx to document a class with a lot of methods.  I'd like to group the methods into sections, separated by headers, like this:

```
.. autoclass:: MyClass

   .. automethod:: __init__

   FooBar Methods
   --------------

   .. automethod:: foo
   .. automethod:: bar

   BazQux Methods
   --------------

   .. automethod:: baz
   .. automethod:: qux
```

But that doesn't seem to work.  Is it possible to somehow break the method list up into named sections?

Answer (score 4):

Sections with headings are top-level constructs and they can't be used inside directives. But [`rubric`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/para.html?highlight=rubric#directive-rubric) works. Example:

```
.. autoclass:: MyClass

   .. automethod:: __init__

   .. rubric:: FooBar Methods

   .. automethod:: foo
   .. automethod:: bar
```